# BASH: Adding existing filecontent to an existing file

Tags: linux, bash, find, eof

I've to add the *content* of a *file* to the end of every `prefs.js` file.
Tried it with `find -name 'prefs.js' -exec more filecontent >> '{}' \;` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirection does not happen for each file (this is tricky). The workaround is to spawn a new shell for each file:

```
find -name 'prefs.js' -exec sh -c 'cat filecontent >> $1;' - '{}' \;
```

The `-` is necessary, as it becomes the zeroth (`$0`) argument to `sh`

Besides, you have to use `cat` instead of more. More is a pager which allows users to scroll through a document.

Answer (score 1):

Use xargs:

```
find -name 'prefs.js' | xargs -n1 bash -c 'cat content_to_be_added >> $1;' -
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in `find -name 'prefs.js'`
do
    echo $f
    #cat $f >> outfile
    cat infile >> "$f"
done
```

Comment: nope, `filecontent` should be added to each `prefs.js` file

Comment: @Fredrik Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

It works to write a small shell script cbd.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "filecontent" >> "$1"
```

of course yo can replace echo with

```
cat "somefile"
```

and to call

```
find -name 'cbd[0-9].txt' -exec ./cbd.sh '{}' \;
```

in the same directory.

The syntax of the find command with its -exec is a true monster.

Comment: "The syntax of the find command with its -exec is a true monster." Agree!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
find -name 'prefs.js' -exec dd if=filecontent conv=notrunc oflag=append of='{}' \;
```

That is assuming `filecontent` is a file containing what you want to append to the `prefs.js` files.